# django: html submit form and display result in smae page without jumping/rereshing into new page

Tags: html, django, ajax, forms, iframe

I am new to django and html. below is my first test web page of a simple online calculator.

I found a problem that when clicking the "submit" button, it tends to jump to a new web page or a new web tab. this is not what I want.  Once the user input the data and click "submit" button, I want the "result" field on the page directly show the result (i.e. partially update only this field) without refresh/jump to the new page. Also I want the user input data kept in the same page after clicking "submit".

I saw there might be several different ways to do this work, iframe/AJAX. However, I have been searching for answers for 5 days and none of the answers really work for this very basic simple question!!

html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <label>num_1:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_1" value="1" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>num_2:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_2" value="2" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

view.py

```
def post_list(request):
    result = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
        num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
        print(request.POST)
        print(result)

    context = {
        'result': result
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

Comment: Could you do all the calculation/updates purely in JS? No need for AJAX then

Comment: I dont write JS. I only write java and python that's why I am using django